# Add row, date picker script is not working after adding other functionality screen

Tags: ajax, jsp

Add row script is not working after adding other functionality screen.

I am trying to do dynamically adding table tows when user clicks "addrow" button. It works when i do it separately. But when i add along with my main jsp code which has other functionality script, that time its not working. Please help me on this.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>section</title>
<style>

</style>
<!--  date picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
<!--  addrows functionality -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=1;    
$("button").click(function(){
        $('#add'+i).html("<td><select name='inpparameter0"+i+"'id='input_parameter'><option value='P1'>Type/Rating</option><option value='P2'>Operating Check</option><option value='P3'>Ext.Apperance</option><option value='P4'>Verify TC</option><option value='P5'>Material</option<option value='P6'>Dimension Check</option><option value='P7'>Threads Check</option>  <option value='P8'>Visual Check</option><option value='P9'>Specification</option><option value='P10'>Batch no</option><option value='P11'>Mfg. Date</option><option value='P12'>Exp. Date</option></select></td><td><select name='inpspec0"+i+"' id='input_spec'><option value='S1'>As per PO</option><option value='S2'>Damage</option><option value='S3'>OK</option><option value='S4'>Stainless Steel</option><option value='S5'>Gaues</option><option value='S6'>Mild Steel</option><option value='S7'>As per Drawing]</option><option value='S8'>Cast Iron</option><optionvalue='S9'>Copper</option><optionvalue='S10'>Aluminium</option><optionvalue='S11'>Brass</option><option value='S12'>Spring Steel</option><option value='S13'>Tool Steel</option></select>  </td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact1"+i+"' id='inpact1' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact2"+i+"' id='inpact2' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact3"+i+"' id='inpact3' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact4"+i+"' id='inpact4' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact5"+i+"' id='inpact5' value='NIL'></td>");
 
$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="add'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;   
  });

});
</script>
<script>
<!-- For calling Populate Table Servlet for getting Item list -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tablediv").hide();
     $("#showTable").click(function(event){
           $.post('PopulateTable',{pono : $('#pono').val()},function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#itemtable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#itemtable");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                 var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                rowNew.children().eq(0).html('<input type="checkbox"/>');
                     rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemname']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemcode']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['supplier']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['totalqty']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"/>');
                        rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"/>');
                        rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"/>');
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                });
                }
            });
            $("#tablediv").show();          
  });      
});
</script>
</script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#find").click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
   url : 'callserv0',
   type: 'POST',
   data : {
    grnno : $('#grn').val()
   },
   success : function(data) {
    alert("Please hold on!");
    var str = data;
   var res = str.split(",");
    $('#pono').val(res[0]);
    $('#podt').val(res[1]);
    return false; 
   }
  });
 });
});
</script>
<script>
/* function to show dropdown list of print menu*/
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
/* reload the page when user clicks new button*/
function myfun1() {
    location.reload(true);
}
/* to allow only numerical values in GRn field*/
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<img border="0" src="mwlogo.gif" alt="logo" id="topright">
<header><h1>testing</h1></header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfun1()">Newreload</a></li>
  <li><a href="#help">Helptest</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.html">Logout</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Print</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">Print Current Report</a>
      <a href="#">Print Preview</a>
      <a href="#">Print Report for given date</a>
      <a href="#">Print Report for given period</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
Receipt number: <input type="text" id="grn" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required/>
<input type="button" id="find" value="Find" class="button0"/>
Type of Evaluation <select name="Evalu">
 <option value="electrical">Electrical</option>
 <option value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
</select>
Unit <select name="unit">
  <option value="unit1">xx</option>
  <option value="unit2">yy</option>
  <option value="unit3">zz</option>
  <option value="unit5">rr</option>
</select>
<br>
 Report No <input type="text" name="irepno" maxlength="8"/>
Inspection date <input type="date" name="inspdate" id="datepicker" required/>
<br></br>
POod number: <input type="text" id="pono" />
POdt Date : <input type="text" id="podt" />
doc No <input type="text" name="invno"/>
doc Date <input type="text" name="invdate"/>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Show Item List" id="showTable" class="button1"/>
<br/>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center"> 
    <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <th scope="col">Item name</th> 
        <th scope="col">Item code</th> 
        <th scope="col">Supplier</th> 
        <th scope="col">Received qty</th>   
        <th scope="col">Accepted qty</th>   
        <th scope="col">Rejected qty</th>      
        <th scope="col">Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
<br></br>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="tab_logic" >
<tr>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="91" align="center">Parameters</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="150" align="center">Specification</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="150" align="center">Actual1</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="50" align="center">Actual2</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="50" align="center">Actual3</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="50" align="center">Actual4</th>
 <th class="Header_Cell" width="50" align="center">Actual5</th>
</tr>
<tr id ='add0'>
 <td>
  <select name="inpparameter0" id="input_parameter">
  <option value="P1">Type/Rating</option>
  <option value="P2">Operating Check</option>
  <option value="P3">Ext.Apperance</option>
  <option value="P4">Verify TC</option>
  <option value="P5">Material</option>
  <option value="P6">Dimension Check</option>
  <option value="P7">Threads Check</option>
  <option value="P8">Visual Check</option>
  <option value="P9">Specification</option>
  <option value="P10">Batch no</option>
  <option value="P11">Mfg. Date</option>
  <option value="P12">Exp. Date</option>
  </select> 
 </td> 
 <td>
  <select name="inpspec0" id="input_spec">
  <option value="S1">As per PO</option>
  <option value="S2">Damage</option>
  <option value="S3">OK</option>
  <option value="S4">Stainless Steel</option>
  <option value="S5">Gaues</option>
  <option value="S6">Mild Steel</option>
  <option value="S7">As per Drawing]</option>
  <option value="S8">Cast Iron</option>
  <option value="S9">Copper</option>
  <option value="S10">Aluminium</option>
  <option value="S11">Brass</option>
  <option value="S12">Spring Steel</option>
  <option value="S13">Tool Steel</option>
  </select> 
 </td> 
 <td class="Body_Cell"><input type="text" name="inpacta0" id="inpact1" value="NIL"/></td>
 <td class="Body_Cell"><input type="text" name="inpactb0" id="inpact2" value="NIL"/></td> 
 <td class="Body_Cell"><input type="text" name="inpactc0" id="inpact3" value="NIL"/></td> 
 <td class="Body_Cell"><input type="text" name="inpactd0" id="inpact4" value="NIL"/></td> 
 <td class="Body_Cell"><input type="text" name="inpacte0" id="inpact5" value="NIL"/></td>               
</tr>
</table>
<br>       
<input type="button" value="Addrow" id="addrow" class="button1" style="float: right;">
<input type="button" value="Save the record" class="button0">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used the id of the button while using the click event listener. You have used the 'button' class. Please use 'addrow' id of button to trigger the event. Also, use `.on` for triggering click events as `.click` doesn't work when DOM is manipulated. Move the `$('#tab_logic').append` above `$("#addrow").on('click',function(){` because on first click there will be no `<tr>` to append the row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;    
    $("#addrow").on('click',function(){
            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="add'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            $('#add'+i).html("<td><select name='inpparameter0"+i+"'id='input_parameter'><option value='P1'>Type/Rating</option><option value='P2'>Operating Check</option><option value='P3'>Ext.Apperance</option><option value='P4'>Verify TC</option><option value='P5'>Material</option<option value='P6'>Dimension Check</option><option value='P7'>Threads Check</option>     <option value='P8'>Visual Check</option><option value='P9'>Specification</option><option value='P10'>Batch no</option><option value='P11'>Mfg. Date</option><option value='P12'>Exp. Date</option></select></td><td><select name='inpspec0"+i+"' id='input_spec'><option value='S1'>As per PO</option><option value='S2'>Damage</option><option value='S3'>OK</option><option value='S4'>Stainless Steel</option><option value='S5'>Gaues</option><option value='S6'>Mild Steel</option><option value='S7'>As per Drawing]</option><option value='S8'>Cast Iron</option><optionvalue='S9'>Copper</option><optionvalue='S10'>Aluminium</option><optionvalue='S11'>Brass</option><option value='S12'>Spring Steel</option><option value='S13'>Tool Steel</option></select>    </td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact1"+i+"' id='inpact1' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact2"+i+"' id='inpact2' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact3"+i+"' id='inpact3' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact4"+i+"' id='inpact4' value='NIL'></td><td class='Body_Cell'><input type='text' name='inpact5"+i+"' id='inpact5' value='NIL'></td>");
            i++;   
      });

});
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help!

Comment: but date picker also not working when i added along with!! what would be the problem

Comment: @Jsel No problem :) :)